# Jeopardy template for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am supposed to be making a jeopardy game for my class. I was wondering it there is a template for it already out? Or do I have to make one myself, in which case, what would be the best approach to making this game in Silverlight? (My last resort is to make it in PowerPoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no template such as this today.

You would need to do a great amount of research into game development in Silverlight to be successful, and that information is too involved to fit into a single question like this.